# No muestra foto en label de tkinter al mandar la direccion de la imagen a una variable String

Tags: python, tkinter

tengo un problema
En mi programa quiero cargar una imagen desde el gestor de archivos y mostrarla en un label de tkinter en python 3.7 (Spyder 4), puedo hacer que muetre una imagen si yo mismo le pongo la direccion

```
Dir=""
ImagenIcon=PhotoImage(file="Imagen.png")
```

este es el ejemplo, la imagen esta en la misma carpeta donde tengo mi programa.

```
def abrir_archivo():
    archivo_abierto=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Seleccione archivo",filetypes = (("png files","*.png"),("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))


    ImagenIcon2=Label(Editor, image=ImagenIcon).place(x=145, y=350)


    global Dir
    Dir = str(archivo_abierto)


    print(Dir)
```

en "archivo_abierto" se guarda la direccion de la imagen, ya comprobe que se guarde la dirección, usando la variable en otra funcion para ver que imprimia, el problema es que al introducirla en PhotoImage no carga la imagen en el label, pero si yo creo una variable con la dirección por defecto y la introduczco en el photoImage, si carga la imagen, sinceramente no se que tengo mal y perdón si no me supe expresar. Espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImagenIcon2=Label(Editor, image=archivo _abierto).place(x=145, y=350)

Intenta así aver si te funciona

Y aquí quítale el "str":
Dir = archivo_abierto

Comment: Muchas gracias, por fin pude resolverlo, declare ImagenIcon sin parametros "ImagenIcon=PhotoImage()" y en el metodo de abajo use la funcion "config" para añadirle la imagen desde el metodo "ImagenIcon.config(image=archivo_abierto) y funcionó :D mil gracias aún así

Comment: @jamesfsk Ah vale vale bien eso